# The area of an obtuse triangle with the longest side length equal to 10 cannot equal to 25.5

Tags: geometry

Need to prove that the area of an obtuse triangle with the longest side length equal to 10 cannot be equal to 25.5

Comment: Hint obtuse angle is opposite to longest site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le $AB$ be the longest side: assume that the origin is the midpoint of $AB$ and $AB$ is oriented like the $x$-axis. Since $\widehat{BCA}>\frac{\pi}{2}$, the vertex $C$ belongs to the half-circle:
$$ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<25, y>0\}$$
hence the distance from the $AB$-side is less than $5$ and the area is less than $\frac{10\cdot 5}{2}=25$.